# Working with ASP MVC Core RC1 and ASPNET_ENV

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

If I have my app running locally, the project file's properties show `hosting:environment` as the key for setting the app's environment (Development, Staging, Production).

It seems that same key is also mapped to `ASPNET_ENV`. Is that right? If so, how and why?

Comment: Are you using RC1 or RC2?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin RC1, title updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/706

- `ASPNET_ENV`. Obsolete.
- `Hosting:Environment`. Use this for RC1 in Windows.
- `Hosting__Environment`. Use this for RC1 in Linux & OS X.
- `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT`. This is the future. Use this in RC2.

[Here is a link to the RC1 release](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/IHostingEnvironment.cs#L14-L15), which says `EnvironmentName`:

> Gets or sets the name of the environment. This property is automatically set by the host to the value of the "Hosting:Environment" (on Windows) or "Hosting__Environment" (on Linux & OS X) environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. This answers the first part of my question. I'm going to remove the extra stuff and put it in a separate question.